# Extra whitespace in fluid table cell div

Tags: css, layout, mobile, html

Please take a look at my fiddle.  I am trying to have a input field next to a 32x32 icon.  For some reason there is white space that hangs off the bottom of my div.  Both the div and image should be 32x32px  I'm doubtful it's my browser but I can't figure it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/WbhgA/1/

Here's what I'm seeing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAMNR.jpg

Comment: What browser are you seeing the space because my fiddle looks good

Comment: Firefox 9.01.  The accepted answer's fiddle works properly.

Comment: it's incorrect, you just needed to specify the vertical align on the inputHolder, it's in my updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/WbhgA/15/

```
.inputHolder {
    height: 32px;
    margin-right: 60px;            
}

.inputHolder input {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 6px;  
    width:100%;  
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

.icon {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -32px;
    background: transparent url(http://icons-search.com/img/fasticon/icomic_lnx.zip/icomic_lnx-icons-32X32-web.png-32x32.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have padding-right of 20px on the input div

so

```
.inputHolder {
   display:table-cell;
   width:100%;
   height:32px;
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/WbhgA/13/

Update: oh that space

you just need to align it vertically

```
.inputHolder {
   display:table-cell;
   width:100%;
   height:32px;
   border:1px solid red; 
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter.  take it out and it still does the same thing.  The issue is that whitespace hangs off the bottom of the icon

Comment: Well then what browser because here http://jsfiddle.net/WbhgA/13/ there is no space